# Cannot merge 2 branches correctly

Tags: eclipse, git, git-merge

I am using Eclipse git, with project in eclipse. I recently did a merge with another branch, and I'm having problems. My project is like this:

```
->project/
    ->configuration/
    ->source/
    ->tools/
```

The code merges correctly in the `configurations` and `source` folders, but not in the `tools` folder.

The other branch has a folder in `tools` called `eth`, which is not being merged with my branch. My branch does not have that folder `eth` in `tools`.

Help me.

Comment: can you paste the error message ?

Comment: There is no error message. When I try to merge the code, it merges, but just the `source` and `configuration` folders. If I try to merge again it says "Already up-to-date".

Comment: can you provide merge error message and commits tree of these branches?

Comment: @ctrl-shift-esc are the branch without `eth` folder have commits there files in this folder was removed?

Comment: @PhillipKovalev I have the branch without the `eth` folder. The other branch has the `eth` folder. I want the `eth` folder.

Comment: @ctrl-shift-esc You have parent (P) without `eth`, branch (A) without files in the `eth` (and `eth` is never been in this branch A), branch (B) there you have created files in the `eth`, and in the active branch A `git merge B` was executed, right?

Comment: @ctrl-shift-esc Commits tree can be very helpful to solve your problem. You can remove a sensitive commit messages from it if project code isn't public, and save only remarks as "file in the `eth` added" which is meaning.

Comment: I don't know what happened, but it worked :D